PyModbus Serial coommunication response speed
Please can you help me to solve my problem.
I want to know the actual speed of response to my request "read holding registers". Can I get this information using pycharm and sending this request?
For now I don't really understand how to do that.

is this a matter of reading time.time() before and after your request = client.read_holding_registers() call or do you need something different?

Thank You very much) I am something like new in python.)

Possibly related: How to use the timeit module

to clarify, do you want to know how much time the modbus request lasts?

Yes, I want to know how much time it lasts, I've already understood)
